# Navigation Bar is Black during Custom Unwind Segue

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios11, swift4, uistoryboardsegue, xcode9

I made a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` but when it unwinds, it seems to cause my `UINavigationBar` to go black, then back to it's correct color. See the GIF below.

[image]

My custom segue just makes the the new ViewController come down from the top and leave going back up to the top.

Here is the `UIStoryboardSegue` code:

```
import UIKit

class SlideDownSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

var duration: Double = 0.5

override func perform() {

    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    let toVC = self.destination
    let fromVC = self.source

    toVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -screenHeight)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.insertSubview(toVC.view, aboveSubview: fromVC.view)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        toVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }, completion: {
        success in
        fromVC.present(toVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    })
}
}

class UnwindSlideDownSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform() {

    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    let toVC = self.destination
    let fromVC = self.source.parent!

    fromVC.view.superview?.insertSubview(toVC.view, at: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        fromVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -screenHeight - 100)
    }, completion: {
        success in
        fromVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    })
}
}
```

If I let the unwind do the default where it just leaves by going to to the bottom of the screen but keep my custom for showing the new View, the `UINavigationBar` maintains it's correct color, it's only when I used my code provided for unwind that the `UINavigationBar` goes black during the animation.

Any hints would be much appreciated.

---***EDIT***---

I played with it a little, if I go into the AppDelegate and change `UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false` to true, I instead get a white background, but then it just appears that the Navigation Bar is suddenly appearing. I'm wondering if it is for some reason being unloaded and then loaded back in once the View Controller is active.

---***EDIT 2***---

I am sorta able to fix it with a hack. In the `AppDelegate` inside `func application(... didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ...)` I added in `self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.{your color}` but all that does is make that black part now appear my color, the Navigation Bar is still disappearing during the segue for some reason.

Comment: Try setting the background color of the navigation controller's view to match. Since you did that can you add another gif?

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect opportunity to use `snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates:)`. That's how `UIKit` performs many of their stock transitions (even in `UINavigationController`) and it's a tremendous way to perform custom transitions, particularly if you want to apply effects. Take a snapshot of the destination (which will have an intact navigation bar), insert it right below the source, perform the animation, dismiss the source so that the destination is ready, and finally remove the snapshot which you won't even notice because it will mirror the destination exactly.

Comment: This sounds very interesting, I'll look into how this works and how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: I don't suppose you have some example code you could give me, do you?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/iabuseservers/c1bb48682b65d7d431454b02ba8d12c5 there is an animation I made for a custom modal presentation that uses `snapshotView()`. Segues, presents, shows, they're basically all the same and the principles of `snapshotView` definitely do not change. Hope that helps.

Comment: Another cool thing in that gist is how you can use `CATransaction` as a wrapper around `UIView.animate()` to be able to add custom timing functions (aka easing). You don't have to use the stock curves like `easeIn` or `easeInOut`, you can make your own using control points. `let timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.25, 0.75, 0.25, 1)` and a great tool for creating them is http://netcetera.org/camtf-playground.html

Comment: By the way, if you want to see this for yourself, push to a view controller with a text field and a keyboard and open it so that the cursor in the text field is blinking. Then pop that view controller with a pan gesture so you can hold it there and you will see the cursor stop blinking (because it's a snapshot). When you let go, the snapshot is removed and the cursor starts blinking again. I think `UINavigationController` uses snapshots on both the `to` and `from` view controllers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very amateur when it comes to programming in Xcode. I have a few questions, first I get an error for Timekeeper, is there a module I have to import to use that? Also, I've created the class using your GitHub link (thank you for that), but how do I use it now. Is it something I call from my custom segue?

Comment: The code I posted is just something I pulled from a project of mine. Maybe I should have taken out the extraneous parts, like Timekeeper (which is just something specific to that project). I posted it to show you how `snapshotView()` can be used. That class is just an animation controller object that you use with the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` to create custom modal presentations. You don't need it for your project, you can stick to what you're doing. But where you insert `toVC.view` you can instead insert `snapshotView()` of it instead. Does that make sense?

Comment: Notice in my gist that instead of inserting the actual view controllers into the animation and manipulating them, I added snapshots of those view controllers and manipulate the snapshots. Then when the animations are complete, I remove the snapshots where the actual view controllers lie underneath.

Comment: Interesting, I actually tried doing that first, just using the snapshotView(), but it for whatever reason still doesn't include the navigation bar... So then I tried using your class and realized I had no idea how to use it. I'll keep plucking away to see if I can get it to work for me though.

Comment: So your navigation bar is persistent then which means you need a snapshot of the screen itself, not just the view controller's view (which, of course, won't contain the nav bar since it's inside another view). To take a snapshot of the entire screen you can do `let snapScreen = appDelegate.window!.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)!`

Comment: I'm thinking I must just have something else completely wrong, I used `let snapScreen = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)!` but that just takes a snapshot of the from ViewController, and even then, it's under the Blank Navigation Bar. I really appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple trick ,try to set background color to `window` in `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to your navigationbar's color, it works for me :)
like this
`window?.backgroundColor = myColor`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that is what I have working in my Edit 2 section already, I was just hoping for the real solution to the navigation bar. Thank you again.